# Recover data of app not on Play anymore?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, data-recovery

Seems I deleted an app or a directory too much from my [Android 2.3 phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_Sonic). In particular I remember removing an app called App2SD or similar. Now, after booting the phone, I cannot see the apps anymore that were installed on the MicroSD card. However, I would like to access data from one app in particular. This app is called Epistle, and I was thinking about simply reinstalling it. However, it is not available on the Play store anymore.

*What strategy can I use to get access to the data of that app?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found a copy Epistle on the web, and installed it using:

```
adb install 2388.-Epistle_v1.2.1.apk
```

Now I can see old data again!

*Warning:* I was aware of the risk that during installation the app may reinitialize its database. If that had happened, then bad luck. The data was comprised of some notes that, while nice to have, would not have been terrible to lose.

Answer (score -1):

I have a suggestion. In fact, some recovery programs can help you like excellent Tenorshare Android Data Recovery. It can recover lost apps data, photos, contacts etc within several seconds. Of course, you can try others